# Difference between string, cell array of strings, vector of strings, and matrix of strings in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I am trying to write a routine that can print any kind of such inputs to a text file.

How can I differentiate between a single-string, a cell array of strings, a vector of strings, and a matrix of strings?

I.e. I want to differentiate,

1. `'My name is X'`
2. `{'My', 'name', 'is', 'X'}`
3. `['My', 'name', 'is', 'X']`
4. `['My', 'name' ; 'is', 'X']`

I wrote the following routine. But, it is not working as expected. For instance,

```
string_list = ['my', ' ', 'name', 'is', ' ', 'xyz!'];
write_string('write_string.txt', string_list);
```

or,

```
string_list = 'my name is xyz!';
write_string('write_string.txt', string_list);
```

output

```
m   y       n   a   m   e   i   s       x   y   z   !
```

**Source Code**

```
function write_string(file_name, string_list)
    mode = 'a';
    fid = fopen(file_name, mode);    

    d = size(string_list);
    l = length(d);

    % vector or cell-array
    if(l==2)
        N = length(string_list);

        % a cell array of strings
        if(iscell(string_list))    
            display('Cell array');
            for k=1:N
                fprintf(fid, '%s\t', string_list{k});
            end
            fprintf(fid, '\n');
        % a vector of strings
        elseif(isvector(string_list))
            display('Vector');
            for k=1:N
                fprintf(fid, '%s\t', string_list(k));
            end
            fprintf(fid, '\n');
        % a single string    
        else
            display('single string');
            fprintf(fid, '%s\t', string_list);
            fprintf(fid, '\n');
        end
    % A matrix of strings
    elseif(l==3)
        % TODO
        fprintf(fid, '\n');
    end   

    fclose(fid);
end
```

Comment: What does `not working` mean?.  Does it error out, if so, what's the error?  Does it not give the expected output, is so, what do you expect and what are you getting?  Note that your 3rd example is no different from the single string 'MynameisX', while your 4th example is invalid MATLAB syntax since all rows in a matrix must have the same number of columns.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Is the goal to try to determine the type of the input parameter, or is it to write some string to a file? What is the desired output in your example? What was the type detected by your code in this instance?

Comment: @beaker, I am trying to write a routine that can print any kind of such inputs to a text file.

Comment: ... and which part of that seems to not be working correctly? Have you tried the code in each `if`/`else` clause individually to see if they give you the desired result? Do your conditions work on your test variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably being confused by not realizing that you aren't really creating an array of strings, rather, you are creating a matrix of characters.

Your `string_list` is a 1x14 matrix of chars: `my nameis xyz!` (note you are missing a space between `name` and `is`).  Then within your code `fprintf(fid, '%s\t', string_list(k))` is taking each element of that string and printing it with a tab character between elements, which is what you are getting.

You have 2 choices:

Use a cell array of strings (which is your example 2).  In your code you can check if you have a cell array of strings (i.e. characters) using `iscellstr`.  Note also, that you don't need to loop to print this out

```
if iscellstr(string_list)
   fprintf('%s\t',string_list{:});
else
   % just a char matrix
   fprintf('%s\t',string_list);
end
```

Or, if you are using a more recent version of MATLAB (R2016b or later I think) then there ***is*** a string data type, and it is created using double quotes, not single quotes

```
string_list = ["my", " ", "name", "is", " ", "xyz!"];
if isstring(string_list)
   fprintf('%s\t',string_list)
end
```